# Java TLS1.0 POODLE

Tags: tls, java

Does java implementation affected?

https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/12/08/poodleagain.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your Java implementation, but none of them are known to be vulnerable at this time.

POODLE over TLS requires that the server has a defective TLS parser that fails to reject certain types of invalid TLS padding.  Currently, only hardware SSL endpoints from A10 Networks and F5 Networks are known to be vulnerable (well, and servers using the NSS library from June 2010 or earlier).